# wp8 ios audio recording and playback compatibility

Tags: ios, audio, windows-phone-8, recording, aac

I want to get playing audio recordings from iOS on WP8 and vice-versa.

On iOS I'm using AVAudioRecorder for that purpose with the following configuration:

```
NSString *tempPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.aac"]];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],
                                AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:8000],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error = nil;

_audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error];

_audioRecorder.delegate = self;
```

The files "sound.aac" contains the recording in the AAC container and playing recorded audio sample works well on iOS.

I couldn't play the "sound.aac" on WP8 after transfering the file to the WP8 device. According the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_AudioSupport WP8 should be able to play the file.
The code on WP8 I've used is:

```
try
{
    this.mediaPlayer = new MediaElement();
    mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(mediaPlayer_MediaEnded);

    IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    IsolatedStorageFileStream mediaStream = myStore.OpenFile("sound.aac", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    this.mediaPlayer.SetSource(mediaStream);
    this.messageTextBlock.Text = "Playing the message...";
    mediaPlayer.Play();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error playing audio!");
    Debug.WriteLine(exception);
    return;
}
```

After this the "sound.aac" is playing endlessly with no sound coming from speaker. The message "Playing the message..." is shown, there is no thrown Exception, no mediaPlayer_MediaEnded call. All I can do is to stop the playing.

I don't know how to get it working.

Comment: What does the MediaFailed event has to say about this?

Comment: MediaFailed says nothing, it is not called at all. No Event of MediaElement is fired after Play()